# Unity2D: Restricting player controlled characters from moving each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making 2d tour based platform game in style simillar to Worms games. There is one thing that i would like to recreate in my game, which is the way that team members are interacting with each other.

I'm looking for a solution to lock the velocity transfer between characters. Let's say that one character which is currently under controll of player is moving towards another character that is in Idle state. When those characters comes into collision, the one that is controllable should not be able to move further forward. But instead, when the first one is still moving, it starts to move second one.

So i'm looking for a solution to prevent the situation when velocity of currently controlled character is transfering to other characters.

Below is a PlayerController script that is responsible for moving the characters:

```
private float MoveSpeed = 5f;
private float JumpSpeed = 15f;
private float MoveInput;

private Rigidbody2D rb;

public bool FacingRight = true;
public bool Grounded;
private bool Jump;

public Transform GroundCheck;
public Transform HealthTag;
public LayerMask Ground;

public Animator animator;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Grounded == true)
    {
        Jump = true;

        if (Jump == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, JumpSpeed);
        }       
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, 0.5f, Ground);

    if(Grounded == false)
    {
        Jump = false;
    }

    MoveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(MoveInput));

    rb.velocity = new Vector2(MoveInput * MoveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

    if (MoveInput > 0 && FacingRight == false)
    {
        Flip();
    }

    else if (MoveInput < 0 && FacingRight == true)
    {
        Flip();
    }        
}

void Flip()
{
    FacingRight = !FacingRight;

    if (FacingRight == true)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        HealthTag.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    }
    if (FacingRight == false)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
        HealthTag.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the rigidbody of the idle player to kinematic. This will prevent it from being pushed by the moving player.